# Bash - Script goes from 3% CPU usage to 100% when run for a long time

Tags: linux, bash, cpu, cpu-usage

I have written a script that collects some system stats. This is run alongside stress tests so that the sats can be collected regarding the system. The stats that are collected include CPU usage (using sar), memory usage (using free), interrupts and so on.  Each of the data points being collected are spawned into separate processes by putting it into the background. There is some post processing done to move this data to a csv file so that it can be opened in a spreadsheet. The post processing also happens in the spawned process. The script has a sleep interval between samples being collected. But, the background processes are still running during this time interval.

I have observed that when this script runs for a long time, the CPU usage for THIS script alone gradually increases from around 3% to almost 100% . This is a disturbing scenario as a profiling script cannot be allowed to take up so much of CPU time. (I am using "top" to record per process CPU usage").

Another interesting observation is that heavy duty processes running in the stress test are taking up lesser CPU time than this script (after its usage crosses 90%).

How can this be resolved? Is there something I am missing here? Please advice.

Adding some code bits below.. The following is the main loop.

```
while true
do

    if [ $exitstatus = 0 ]
    then
        exitScript
    fi
    let itr++
    echo -e "\n Interation: $itr\n"

    if [ "$3" = "ALL" ]
    then
        export CALC_INTERRUPTS=1
        printTitle "sar"
        processCommand "sar" &

        #printTitle "free"
        processCommand "free" &

        printTitle "interrupts"
        processCommand "interrupts" &

        printTitle "underflows"
        processCommand "underflows" &


        #printTitle "clocktree"
        processCommand "clocktree" &

    else    
        if [ $itr -eq 1 ]
        then
            shift 2
        fi
        for com in "$@"
        do
            printTitle "$com"
            processCommand "$com" &

        done
    fi
    #printTimestamp > $TEMP_LOC/sys.log
    cat /var/log/syslog > $TEMP_LOC/sys.log
    if [ $exitstatus = 0 ]
    then
        exitScript
    fi
    sleep $interval
    #Wait for background jobs from the last iteration to finish     
    for job in `jobs -p`
    do      
        wait $job 
    done

    cat $TEMP_LOC/*.temp >> $TEMP_LOC/monitor.log
    rm -f $TEMP_LOC/*.temp

    if [ $(($itr % 180)) -eq 0 ] 
    then
        takeDump
    fi

done
```

fi

The following is the recording and post processing for CPU usage (using sar) -

```
processCommand()
{

case "$1" in
sar)
    printTimestamp>> $TEMP_LOC/$1.temp
    #echo -n " Logging CPU stats............ "
    exe="sar -P ALL 1 1"
    $exe > $TEMP_LOC/temp_sar

    echo -e "\n\n Processes using more than 1% of CPU time: " >> $TEMP_LOC/$1.temp
    top -b -n 1 > $TEMP_LOC/temp_top



    #delete all lines except current CPU statistics
    sed -i "5,8! d" $TEMP_LOC/temp_sar
    #replace all spaces with commas
    sed -i  's/[[:space:]]\+/,/g' $TEMP_LOC/temp_sar

    Cpu=0
    while [ -s $TEMP_LOC/temp_sar ]
    do
        #if file does not exist then add the header 
        if [ ! -f $TEMP_LOC/Cpu$Cpu.csv ]
        then
            printf "time,$Cpu.us,$Cpu.ni,$Cpu.sy,$Cpu.wa,$Cpu.st,$Cpu.id,$Cpu.total\n"  >> $TEMP_LOC/Cpu$Cpu.csv
        fi
        #remove  CPU number 
        stats=`sed -n '1p' $TEMP_LOC/temp_sar | cut -d ',' --complement -f 2`

        idle=`echo $stats | cut -d ',' -f 7`
        #calculate totale CPU usage as 100-idle
        total_usage=$(bc <<< "100.00-$idle")
        echo "$stats,$total_usage" >> $TEMP_LOC/Cpu$Cpu.csv

        sed -i '1d' $TEMP_LOC/temp_sar
        let Cpu++

    done

    ;;
```

Other parts of the code also work similarly. Take a snapshot of that parameter at regular intervals and do some post processing on it.

Comment: Could you post the script content

Comment: Do you keep all the data in memory? Do you overwrite the CSV file or just append new data?

Comment: Gradually increasing # of threads? Also note total CPU% is CPU%/CPU-cores in [tag:top].

Comment: @choroba, yes all the data is in memory. I mount RAMFS and keep all the temporary data on it.

Comment: @krampstudio, the script is pretty big (about 500 lines or so). Do you want me to paste the entire thing?

Comment: @BroSlow, I am not increasing the number of threads. Since it is a Bash script, we can't even have threads right. But I am spwaning processes in the background. The number of processes spwaned is the same for every iteration though and i wait for them to finish before i start the next. I have updated the description with those detains

Comment: @BroSlow Also, Since it is initially showing only 3% i think i am not misinterpreting CPU usage.

Comment: @SKC maybe there are some relevant parts you could paste? I.e. your parallel processing ("threads"? ;) ) logic :)

Answer (score 0):

try use a single awk on /proc "files" instead multiple tools like *free,sar,ps -C*...

```
time awk ' /MemTotal/ {print $2}; /SwapCached/ {print $2}; /processor/ {print $NF}' /proc/meminfo /proc/cpuinfo 
1933536
17840
0
1

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

using a single script without preserving variables on shell you will avoid some memory/cpu leak, like a shell variable that you forget to clean on each loop and you do some grep on that..

Comment: Would memory leak cause CPU usage spike?

Comment: no.. but if memory of this shell script is growing, may reveal some variable constantly in use without be cleaned, and manipulate huge variables does the CPU usage spike
ps. sorry the poor english

Comment: Thanks BrenoZan. will try the same :)